# Hazelcast and Hibernate clarification

Tags: hibernate, distributed-caching, hazelcast

I'm working in a project that uses dropwizard as framework, and hibernate as Java persistence framework.

I've discovered hazelcast to distribute my second cache level in a cluster using the provided annotation @cache into any entity of my project.

But I've a doubt. If I follow the official documentation (http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/latest/manual/single_html/, chapter 13) I need to setup hibernate with some property that set my node as HibernateClientInstance.

So, my question is: if my web app is a node of cluster set as HazelcastClient, where is the central server? I need to run Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(new Config()); at the bootstrap of my web app instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have to set your web app as hazelcast client?

If you have hibernate in your web-app then it should behave as an hazelcast server to store the cache.